# How to change the background colour of a UITableViewCell using Core graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-graphics

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) of core graphics. I'm at the point where we change the background colour of the `UITableViewCell`. The result I should get according to the tutorial is this:

[image]

Whereas the result I'm getting is this (The cell which is completely red is the cell that I have selected in the tableview):

[image]

The tutorial is for Xcode 4.6 which is probably why I'm not getting the desired result. This is the code I'm using.

Custom background class:

```
CustomCellBackground.m

-(void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor * redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
}
```

Code for tableview in tableviewcontroller class:

```
TableViewController.m


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSString * entry;

    if (![cell.backgroundView isKindOfClass:[CustomCellBackground class]]) {
        cell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    }

    if (![cell.selectedBackgroundView isKindOfClass:[CustomCellBackground class]]) {
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    }


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        entry = self.thingsToLearn[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        entry = self.thingsLearned[indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = entry;

    return cell;
}
```

Please point out what I'm doing wrong and point me to the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be the height issue. Try to check out what is the height that is getting returned here.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma. I don't think that the height is an issue here. But can you point out why you think so?

Comment: My bad. can you cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Comment: @AkhileshSharma. I used cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]. It worked. Can you explain a little what exactly was happening here?

Comment: Nothing just the textlabel that you adding is having a background color

Comment: @AkhileshSharma. Why wasn't this an issue in the previous version of xcode just as in the tutorial?

Comment: there is a considerable amount of change as per the one you have reffered here. iOS implementation has changed like crazy since the time Xcode 4.6 was used. There are lot things that are added and deprecated since then.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Thanks a lot. Please add the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Anytime :) No worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this setting the label color to clear color as specified below.

SWIFT

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Objective C

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: UIColor.clearColor(); gave me an error. [UIColor clearColor] is the one which gave me my desired result. So please edit your answer to that.

Comment: Updated the text as requested. I provided answer assuming that you are using swift.